# SAS ODS Output: Get Histogram (only!) in PDF

Tags: sas, sas-ods

I'm running the following code to output a histogram of a certain variable:

```
    ods results off;
    ods listing close;
    ods pdf file="&folder/temp.pdf";
    title ;
    * Histogram of betCount;
    proc univariate data=want;
          var BetCount;
          histogram;
    *label sex=' ' height='Height (cm)';
    run;
    ods pdf close;
    ods listing;
    ods results on;
```

It does create a PDF, but there's lots of extra tables and output. I just want to see the histogram only, as I'm read into latex as part of a \minipage with six figures in it. I have done this manually before by taking a screenshot of the required region, pasting into Paint and coverting to PDF or PNG: I don't want to go down that road again! How can this be done in general for graphs and plots in SAS?

Thanks for any help at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can name the graph and then use ODS SELECT to select (only) it.  (ODS TRACE ON will help you see it in the log.)

```
ods trace on;
ods pdf file="c:\temp\myfile.pdf";
ods select histogr;
proc univariate data=sashelp.class;
var age;
histogram age/name="Histogr" ;
run;
ods pdf close;
```